# Move Recurring Appointment to a Different Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

How do I move a recurring appointment to a different calendar in Outlook 2010? If I just drag it to the other calendar, it gives me this error:

[image: Outlook error message when moving recurring appointments]

I am moving the first appointment; the one that I first created and made recurring.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's well hidden but you can move these appointments like this:

1. Open the whole series (not the single appointment)
2. On the upper left select "File" - now this crazy dialog opens
3. Click on "Move to Folder" and select your prefered Folder

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook 2016, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2010, and Outlook 2007 have a keyboard shortcut that will allow you to move items quickly between calendars.

Simply select the calendar item you want to move to a different calendar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This will bring up a dialog that will allow you to specify where you want to *move* your calendar item.

If you keep multiple calendars and have to separate out incoming meeting request often, this shortcut makes life a lot easier.

Microsoft [Shortcut List](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#bkmk_createitem)

Comment: Much faster than the accepted answer, especially since my target calendar didn't appear in the File dialog until I clicked Other Folder.

Comment: This is neat for single appointments, but doesn't for for _recurring_, as the question was about.